# Tensorflow: Custom error aggregator

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose we want to alter the [Abalone regression example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/estimators/abalone.py) so that there is an additional evaluation metric. The metric, called `pctWrong`, is equal to the percentage of predictions whose error is > 1%:
`=== pseudocode ===
pctWrong = countTrue(if (|y-y_hat|/y > 1%) True else False) / countTotal`

```
=== Python ===
105 # Calculate additional eval metrics
106 eval_metric_ops = {
107     "rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(
108         tf.cast(labels, tf.float64), predictions),
109     "pctWrong": ???
110 }
```

How would you go about defining such metric? I found [tf.metrics.percentage_below()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/percentage_below), which might be helpful, but I don't know how to use it. In particular I don't know how to get its `values` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** It wasn't that difficult after all. The code below is a bit rough, but it works.

```
# Calculate additional eval metrics
ys = tf.cast(labels, tf.float64)
y_hats = predictions
losses = tf.divide(tf.abs(tf.subtract(ys, y_hats)), ys)
accuracies = -losses

eval_metric_ops = {
    "rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(tf.cast(labels, tf.float64), predictions),
    "pctWrong": tf.metrics.percentage_below(accuracies, -0.01)
}
```